# What's going on, why isn't this working?

Tags: c, linux

Here is the code. Very basic and should work properly:

```
int main() {
    int n, status, i;
    printf("Please enter an integer bigger than 1: ");

    status = scanf("%d", &n);

    if (status != 1 || n > 1) {
        printf("Invalid input!");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("What is going on %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles good, and after I insert "10" as input, the program does nothing. Just as if it was supposed to `return 0` without doing nothing.

***EDIT***: **The main lesson here is don't post questions when it's late and you're super tired. The accepted answer (and handful of friendly comments) show why**

Comment: How about set breakpoint and debug it?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and inspect the values of the variables and confirm that they agree with your expectations. You should have done that before asking any questions here.

Comment: I get a [runtime error](http://ideone.com/awijjo)

Comment: Why do you consider `n>1` an invalid input?

Comment: `n > 1`  --> `n <= 1`

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: If you want to get it in order, append a newline to the message.. Runtime error is because of `return 1`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why does this matter?

Comment: @UFCInsider Because of line-buffering

Comment: @user45891 Yes, I know - doesn't change the fact that it does not do "nothing" as OP claims.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can't see what's wrong with this question. Please refer to the content

Comment: @UnholySheep you're right I confused you with the OP

Comment: @UFCInsider I mentioned _exactly_ what is wrong, lack of proof of effort.

Comment: Please show us some example of input and expected output: e.g. _When I enter `10`, I expect the program to display ...._

Comment: @MichaelWalz When I enter an integer bigger than 1, I expect to see the printing output of the for loop.

Comment: @UFCInsider OK, now it's a bit clearer. This kind of information belongs __into__ the question. You wrote _the program does nothing_, but that's not enough, we cannot guess what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you not see the problem here?

```
if (status != 1 || n > 1) { // n can not be larger than 1.
    printf("Invalid input!");
    return 1;
}

for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) { // n must be larger than 2.
    printf("What is going on %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... It's too late here. Accepted your answer